# How can I solve this GTID error when restoring through binlogs?

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog, gtid

I have a sequence of `sql` files created with the command `mysqlbinlog binlog.000093 > log93.sql`, from 93 to 109. These logs go back to the creation of the database, so I suppose I can fully restore the database. I need to restore the database to the state it was at a specific datetime.
I tried to execute the command `cat log93.sql | mysql -u root -p` but I get the error `@@SESSION.GTID_NEXT cannot be changed by a client that owns a GTID. The client owns ANONYMOUS. Ownership is released on COMMIT or ROLLBACK.`

I tried two things:

- I added:

```
[mysqlbinlog]
skip-gtids
```

in the `my.cnf` file, but nothing, I get the same error.

- I added (instead of the previous configuration):

```
[mysqld]
enforce_gtid_consistency = 'ON'
gtid-mode = 'ON'
```

but I get the error `@@SESSION.GTID_NEXT cannot be set to ANONYMOUS when @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = ON`.

I am running `mysql  Ver 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`.
How can I solve the issue and effectively restore the database?